# Restful way to return collection of entities not belonging to another entity

Tags: web-services, rest, http, spring-mvc, architecture

Consider I have `Students` and `Subjects`.

It is pretty simple to return all `Subjects` belonging to the `Student`:

```
GET /students/{id}/subjects
```

or just filter list of `Subjects` by `Student`:

```
GET /subjects?studentId={id}
```

But what if I want to return all `Subjects` which are not belonging to the `Student`?

I know I can pass additional boolean parameter like `isBelong` but it is ugly.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just do "GET /subjects" to return them all?

Answer (score 0):

There is not "Restful way". This has nothing to do with rest. Let's call it API aesthetics (or DX since it seems to be trendy nowadays)

If your question is what is a better way than "isBelong", here are some suggestions:

- /subjects?studentId=null
- /subjects?status=unassigned
- /unassigned-subjects
- /subjects/unassigned